# How can I reduce the granularity of login time ago in Views (from minutes to days)?

Tags: views, datetime

I have a view of users which displays fields, one of which is `User: Last login`.  I set the **Date format** to `Time ago (with "ago" appended)`. By default, this returns values like:

- 1 hour 5 minutes ago
- 7 hours 23 minutes ago
- 3 days 17 hours ago

I am sorting the view by `User: Last login` as well, and for this I have set the **Granularity** to `Day`.  For a number of reasons, I would like to prevent users from seeing precisely how long ago another user logged in if that user logged in within the last 24 hours.  So instead, I would like to return values like:

- 1 hour 5 minutes ago-> **Today**
- 7 hours 23 minutes ago-> **Today**
- 3 days 17 hours ago-> **3 days ago**

Is it possible to do something like this as a custom **Date format** in Views?

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more complete now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "dull ax" approach to things, you could do a combination of things here.

1. In the Views UI, under the Date Format, there is a `If "Custom", see the PHP docs for date formats. If "Time ago", enter the number of different time units to display, which defaults to 2.` **Set this to 1.**
2. Now, Views will only output `13 sec ago` `13 min ago` `1 hour ago` etc instead of `1 day 13 hours` etc.
3. This still doesn't get rid of your specificity of the time of the day if today, eg it is going to output `1 sec ago,` `12 min ago` or `3 hour ago,` etc.
4. To take care of that, you can create a views template for that field, eg, here in D6 World it would be something like `views-view-field--NAMEOFVIEW--login.tpl.php`.
5. In there, do something along the lines of:

```
if (strpos($output, 'sec') !== FALSE || strpos($output, 'min') !== FALSE || strpos($output, 'hour') !== FALSE) {
  print t('Today');
}
else {
  print $output;
}
```

which will print out `Today` if it sees a sec, min or hour, or the default if not, eg, it sees day, week, month etc.

Comment: The fifth step will not work with multilingual sites, but you can improve it.

Comment: true, t('sec'), t('min'), t('hour') would sharpen the ax a bit.

Comment: I tried this: `if (strpos($output, t('sec')) !== FALSE || strpos($output, t('min')) !== FALSE || strpos($output, t('hour')) !== FALSE) {`   This works for English, but it doesn't work for Japanese.  Any ideas?

Comment: check and make sure you have translations for the strings sec, min and hour in Japanese.  I've never done any, but these appear to be a good start on how:  http://drupal.org/contribute/translations and http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update

Comment: if that's not the case, as I am really naive when it comes to internationalization, perhaps mb_strpos() or one of its multibyte cousins is the way to go.

Comment: Well, neither `t()` nor `mb_strpos()` worked; however, in this case I only have one other language, so it's simple enough to add three more sets of || to the if statement.

Comment: glad it's working dull ax style :)  I gotta dig into t() and so forth more and figure that end of things out

Answer (score 2):

I think the logic required for of "Today" vs "3 days ago" rules out using a regular Date format. If you stuck to "X days ago", it would work, but that's not as pretty.

I would implement a custom field formatter that did what you wanted, as it's an easy way to get high control over output.

There is a drawback in this case, since you don't actually have a proper field for "Last login", you need to add 
an extra "dummy" field. It's up to you if this is an acceptable work-around, but I've used this several times myself to no I'll effect. If you put it on a end-user editable entity, you will probably want to deny access to the field for users though, so it doesn't clutter the UI.

To keep topics separate, I posted that as a separate question. [How do I make the output of field X look like Y?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36351/how-do-i-make-the-output-of-field-x-look-like-y).